# Postgresql: ON CONFLICT UPDATE only if new value has been provided

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  a VARCHAR(32),
  b VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  c VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (a)
);
```

and this "UPSERT" type query:

```
INSERT INTO 
  myTable ( a,  b,  c)
  VALUES  ($1, $2, $3)
ON CONFLICT (a)
  DO UPDATE SET
    b = $2,
    c = $3,
RETURNING
  a, b, c
;
```

This works as expected.  If I first insert (json for notational convenience):

```
{a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}
```

then I can update it with params like this:

```
{a:"a", b:"x", c:"y"}
```

And I get the expected result-- the {a:"a"} record has updated `b` and `c` columns.

But I would like to also be able to do this:

```
{a:"a", c:"Q"}
```

and update the `c` column ***while leaving column `b` intact.***

Of course, I need some kind of expression on the right hand side, but I don't know what that is.  My intuition is something like this (SQL pseudocode):

```
...
  DO UPDATE SET
    b = ($2 | b)
    c = ($3 | c)
...
```

What's the right syntax here?  Or, is there a completely different method I should be using?

Comment: You mean leave b alone no matter what?  If so, just omit it from the "set."  DO UPDATE SET c = $3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()`. The idea is to pass a `NULL` value to one of the parameters, and then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a,  b,  c)
VALUES  ($1, $2, $3) 
DO UPDATE SET
    b = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.b, b)
    c = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.c, c)
```

When a record already exists with `a = $1` *and* `$1` or `$2` are given a `null` value and , then only the non-`null` value is written.

The downside is that this query will not be able to assign a `null` value to an already-existing record.

Side note: this uses pseudo-table `EXCLUDED` rather than repeating the parameters.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about COALESCE().  I ended up getting null values I wanted by using `b=NULLIF(COALESCE($1, b), '')`.  For my purposes, when someone sets a value to blank, its effectively NULL.

Comment: Actually, this code returns error "column reference "b" is ambiguous". To avoid it? someone have to use allias for the table myTable.

Comment: This doesn't work if b has a non-null constraint

Answer (score 1):

You can use COALESCE() and not forget to use allias for th table myTable

```
INSERT INTO myTable as t (a,  b,  c)
VALUES  ($1, $2, $3) 
DO UPDATE SET
    b = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.b, t.b)
    c = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.c, t.c)
```